Why is String template not available
I updated my JDK to JDK 23 and now get a weak warning for any String concatenations like System.out.print("The capital city of " + index + " is "); saying I should use a String template, but when I apply the IDE quick fix to apply the template, the java.lang.StringTemplate class doesn't exist which I can confirm even after manually looking for the StringTemplate in the JDK 23 library.
Is anyone else missing this class or is it probably an issue with my JDK?
The exact warning message is:

String can be replaced with template


[edit] the question to add the exact warning text, as text please.

How do you build your code? You probably have --target set to something lower than 23.

@talex I don't recall ever setting any target. JDK is 23 language level set to default

JDK 23 Release Notes: "String Templates were first previewed in JDK 21 (JEP 430) and re-previewed in JDK 22 (JEP 459). After feedback and extensive discussion, we concluded that the feature is unsuitable in its current form. There is no consensus on what a better design will be, therefore we have withdrawn the feature for now, and JDK 23 will not include it."  :-(

Are you using Maven or Gradle? Have you got something like javaToolchain, or sourceCompatibility in your build file?

The string template was a preview feature in Java 21 and Java 22, and has been withdrawn for further redesign. In other words, this feature never existed in mainline Java (you needed to enable preview features to use it), and now with the release of Java 23, it doesn't exist at all.
If you get recommendations from IntelliJ to use string templates, you either need to update IntelliJ (it shouldn't suggest this at all for Java 23), or possibly you have set your language level to "21 (Preview)" or "22 (Preview)", instead of normal (non-preview) language level "21", "22" or "23". In other words, go to File, Project Structure, and on Project check the language level, and double-check for individual Modules (on their "Sources" tab).
As an aside, recent Java versions already optimize string concatenation like "The capital city of " + index + " is " pretty well by replacing it with a low-level form of templating in the compiled bytecode.

I'm currently on IntelliJ 2024.2.2 with JDK 23 language level set to default.

@Andruid929 I just checked it with 2024.2.2, and it only reports that suggestion with language level "21 (Preview)" or "22 (Preview)", not with 21, 22, or 23. Double-check if the language level of your Module maybe overrides the project language level.

String Templates were a preview feature of Java 21/22 and were removed in Java 23. The reason given was:

After some experience with the prototype, it became clear that the processor-centric nature of the proposed design was confusing to users and lacked the desired compositionality.

Earlier versions of IntelliJ (2024.1?) were not yet fully aware of all the features of Java 23. As of recent versions (2024.2.2 or possibly earlier) it is now fully compatible with Java 23 and will no longer suggest string templates.

IntelliJ 2024.2.2 doesn't suggest string templates with language level 23.

@MarkRotteveel you're right, thanks, corrected.
